# Standalone SharePoint 2010 Installation on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010, installation

I am installing SharePoint on windows 7 as  a standalone using ServerFarm 
So i m using a standalone server so i do not have a domain account. When  i m using command shell to create database it is giving me following error [image]

I also off windows firewall but no solution if you have any solution please help me

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the shell as Administrator (right-click -> Run As administrator)

Comment: oh God thanks alot Rene it solve the problems again so much thank you